# Match and Display the directory path and its name entered by user using PERL

Tags: perl

I want to display the path and name of the directory when the user enters the directory name using perl. 
Below is the code were i am stuck

```
#!/usr/local/perl/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

print "enter the username\n";
my $username = <STDIN>;

my $dir = '/home';
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
if($dir =~ $username){
    print "Yes I got it.\n";
}
else{
    print "Username not found.\n";
}
closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Comment: `opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die;
    while(readdir $dh) {
    print "$some_dir/$_\n";
    }
    closedir $dh;` this is how you read a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
opendir( $dh, $userdir ) || die "$!";
while( ($filename = readdir(DIR))){
     ### do you matching here with $filename
}
closedir $dh;
```